# mapping unique_ptr to shared_ptr design

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I have an unique_ptr in my main application (which provides some service to other applications).
Now I want to share this instance of unique_ptr to multiple applications which require service from my main application.

The main application will be the owner of that unique_ptr object.

for example, my unique_ptr object might have a set of Qt signals and other applications will listen to these signals for service.

[image]

Right now I'm getting raw pointer from  unique_ptr and returning it to other applications, but what happens if some application **deletes** that raw pointer?

should I change my unique_ptr to shared_ptr and give weak_ptr to other applications?

Comment: Converting to a shared_ptr and passing weak_ptrs seems to be a good idea.

Comment: You can't protect against badly written code running in the same process. A bad caller could, for example, corrupt the heap via a buffer overrun, and cause your main component to crash in a seemingly unrelated, innocent memory allocation. In my humble opinion, a raw pointer is perfectly fine to represent a resource owned by someone else.

Comment: By definition C and C++ are not secure languages and can't be made into one. And the attempts at making a secure "subset" of either I have seen are at best a joke, and frankly more of a con job, as they aren't even proper subsets (they add some constructs), and exclude almost all commonly use feature of either languages so practically no real program would be in the so called subset. You would have to use a completely different PL, and even "safe" PL sometimes provide unsafe features and interfaces that you really need to use!

Comment: You can't design against blatant programming error like explicitly deleting something that should not be deleted. But you can trash the bytes of delete objects so that any attempt to use their value will cause rapid program misbehavior, which is easier to detect and diagnose than late program misbehavior. *They are many simple things you can do to make programming errors more blatant at runtime*, and more complex tools that can help you.

Comment: Why dont you expose the APIs?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no lifetime issue then there is no point to switch to use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`.

About raw pointer in the interface, I agree it can be misleading.
Maybe using a reference could be enough or using an opaque structure that wraps the reference and provide a better interface from outside.